# How can I choose how many columns wide a child element is?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

When I set columns of an element within another column, it uses the total number of columns not the number of columns in the parent. e.g.

```
<div class="therow">
  <div class="acolumn">
    <div class="achildcolumn">
       <!-- my content goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$total-columns: 12 ;

.therow {
  @include grid-row();
  .acolumn {
    @include grid-column(9);
    .achildcolumn {
      @include grid-column(7);
    }
  }
}
```

So I want .achildcolumn to take up 7/9 columns, but it seems to be 7/12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected result. Each sub-grid also uses `$total-columns`. This prevents you from having to add up columns as you nest them.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        50% width
      </div>
      <div class="small-6 columns">
        50% width
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to get more granular with your nested columns one option would be to change `$total-columns` to 24, or even 36. Then you would have ultra-fine control over sub-columns.

Comment: Ok, interesting, the first grid system I used was Semantic Grid, which would let you set the number of columns in the child. I can work with this though, thanks.